# Jquery datepicker submit value to the MVC4 model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker, datapicker

I have following code which is used to be one popup of datepicker in date enrollment field. and want to submit date value to the enrollment field in the database. in short i mean to say i want to pick a date from jquery datepicker instead of giving it manually.  but unluckily never works ... i want when i click over enrollment field there is a popup of jquery datapicker....

my student .cs

```
namespace ContosoSite.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    [MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetadata))]
    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            this.Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollment>();
        }

        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "EnrollmentDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

create.cshtml

```
@model ContosoSite.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>
        <div class="datefield editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>*@
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field " >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />

    </fieldset>
}
<script>
      $(function () {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
  </script>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          $("#EnrollmentDate").datepicker();
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: nice nilesh.... few questions please.... i want this datepicker in the whole site where enrollment field is appeared ... is it posible. for example i use this functiom in the create page ,,, i want this also in the edit page

Comment: you have to only paste above script with proper id & necessary jqueries to that page

Comment: ok thanks.... some times my pahe shows a message :" The value '05/17/2014' is not valid for EnrollmentDate." whats wrong with it

Comment: maybe bcoz of your attribute that you have added in your model...if answer is useful dont forget to mark this as answer

Comment: no worry about that, ur answer and comments all will be marked as helpful dear, upvote my question too plz...

Comment: thnx nilesh we will rockk... yeahh

Comment: u r availble? i hve qustn plz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45274/discussion-between-jatt-net-and-nilesh)